# xcode 4.2.1 which ios sdk?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, version

I have been trying to find online release notes for xcode 4.2.1 but have failed. I want to know which ios sdk is shipped with xcode 4.2.1. At the moment I am developing on osx 10.6.8 (i.e. snow leopard) and am using xcode 4.2. This ships with ios sdk 5.0.0.

Basically I'm wondering if I need to upgrade to os x 10.7 (lion) so that I can then install xcode 4.2.1 in order to get access to ios sdk 5.0.1. I'll do all this if I can find out if ios sdk 5.0.1 is included with xcode 4.2.1 but as I say this information seems to be difficult to come by.

Any help is much appreciated,
Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolution: As I said in my comment above, I upgraded to os x 10.7 and then downloaded xcode 4.2.1. This still did not seem to come with ios sdk 5.0.1 and organizer still gives me the warning about the software image not being found. However, I am now able to launch my project onto my connected iPhone via xcode without the errors that had been coming up with my original configuration. Clarity does not seem to be one of the finer points of xcode development.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 4.2.1 for Lion**

Posted Date: November 17, 2011
Build: 4D502
Included iOS SDK: iOS 5
Included Mac SDK: Mac OS X 10.7

**Xcode 4.2 for Snow Leopard**

Posted Date: October 12, 2011
Build: 4C199
Included iOS SDK: iOS 5
Included Mac SDK: Mac OS X 10.6

Apparently both come with 5.0
Source: http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

As far as i know, iOS 5.1 is still in beta stage and available only for developer accounts.

Here are the release notes for all XCode versions:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html

HTH, Vlad

Comment: Thanks Vlad. I went ahead and upgraded to osx 10.7 and downloaded xcode 4.2.1 hoping that it would include the ios sdk 5.0.1 but the xcode organizer is still telling me that my iPhone has a version of ios (5.0.1) that xcode cannot find a software image for. I could restore the iPhone to 5.0.0 but I would prefer not to have to do this. The exact message given by xcode organizer is as follows:

Comment: "xcode cannot find the software image to install this version"

Answer (score 0):

You can get the release notes for your current xcode from the help menu. Of course, this doesn't help you since you want them for a release you don't have. But, at the start of those release notes it says:

> Important: To get the latest release notes, visit the Mac or iOS Dev Center and go to the Xcode 4 download section.